# Revision history formatting has gone mental again

Tags: bug, revisions-list

See [this revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25342789/revisions#spacer-db0f1900-de73-4412-89f1-2abb211686a6). The *side-by-side markdown* view shows that no code was altered in the revision, but the *side-by-side* view highlights the entire code block as changed … and *inline* view goes totally bonkers in ways that only a screenshot can explain:

#### side-by-side markdown view:

> [image: side-by-side markdown view]

#### side-by-side view:

> [image: side-by-side view]

#### inline view:

> [image: inline view]

Comment: I don't quite see what the problem is here. The original text used code blocks, so the `non-type template argument refers to function that does not have linkage` "code block" is used in an inline diff with the codeblock that replaced it. Note how the word `template` appears in both. The rest of the words are assumed to have been replaced by other 'keywords' in the real-code code block.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well okay they were consecutive code blocks, but it's clear from the positioning of that horizontal scrollbar that they were _separate_ code blocks, and the resulting diff is quite obviously sub-optimal. If nothing else, the way the original code block's content is scattered across the first few lines of the second code block, is just weird.

Comment: The differ sees two codeblocks; one replaced the other in the document order. Now that they are matched up as one replacing the other, the differ tries to match up identifiers. `#include<iostream.h>` apparently contains two, so that's matched with `non type`, etc. The next series of identifiers are `T1`, `T2`, `tempex`, `a` and `b`. Apparently `that`, `does` and `not` are not identifiers (perhaps because `not` is a common keyword).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, I can see what it's doing. I'm saying that it should not be doing that. From a user standpoint it's barmy. The two codeblocks in the original code were distinct, separate blocks with no relationship to one another. The result is this useless mess!

Comment: The original post was a *mess*; any algorithm trying to match up such disparate posts (in terms of structure) is going to fall flat on edge cases like these.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Not if they treat two distinct code blocks as two distinct code blocks, as any sane individual would.

Comment: That's easy for you to say, you clever human. Computer algorithms are not nearly so perceptive.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Right, and this report is posted with the intention of now making the computer algorithm clever enough to recognise that two consecutive code blocks are not one code block! Computers are only as perceptive as we teach them to be.